# ruby on rails ails with couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all'    which is a known issue, I added *=require jquery.ui.all to application.css   and //= require jquery.ui.all to application.js but still get the error.   http://bpaste.net/show/1RqTDUte2XLBoj8fdTbf/

Sprockets::FileNotFound in Preorder#index

Showing /var/www/localhost/htdocs/selfstarter/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all'
  (in /var/www/localhost/htdocs/selfstarter/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:14)

Extracted source (around line #6):

```
3:   <head>
4:     <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
5:     <title><%= Settings.product_name %></title>
6:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
7:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
8:   </head>
9:   <!--[if lt IE 9 ]><body class="lt-ie9"><![endif]-->
```

http://bpaste.net/show/110613/

http://bpaste.net/show/110612/

Comment: complete build  http://bpaste.net/show/3yC1AZxq5WmSTzHHTE4d/

Answer (score -6, accepted):

actually the solution was to clone a fresh copy of my repo an run

```
bundle install --without production
bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundle exec rake db:seed
rails s
```

Answer (score 35):

In version 4 it used to be

```
//= require jquery.ui.all
```

But from version 5.0:

```
application.js:

  //= require jquery-ui

application.css:

  /*
   *= require jquery-ui
  */
```

Comment: This solved my problem when pulling a production environment to a new development environment. Thanks! Accepted answer does not seem to have anything to do with question.

Comment: I was stuck in similar situation, and it worked for me, Thanks for accepting.

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution to me

Comment: this should be the accepted answer not the one the OP wrote and accepted. ugh

Answer (score 11):

In order to require assets from jQuery UI, you need to install it first.

In `Gemfile`, add:

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

Then run `bundle install` and restart the rails server.

Comment: For me, I tried to do `group :assets do gem 'jquery-ui-rails' end`. When I took the `gem` statement out of the `group`, my code started working.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, it must be placed outside of the assets group. And by the way, there is no `:assets` group anymore in Rails 4.

Comment: See the end of section http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#upgrading-from-old-versions-of-rails in case you are using `:assets` group.  You might need to edit `Bundler.require` call in your `config/application.rb`.

Answer (score 6):

I have faced the same problem..

What happened to my project is, my `gemfile.lock` got updated and it was set to use the latest version of all the gems..

In case of `jquery-ui-rails 4.2.1` we have been using `4.2.1` and by mistake `gemfile.lock` got updated and used the `5.0.2`.

> In `jquery-ui-rails 5.0.2` the file `jquery.ui.all.js` is no more available.

So I was facing the error `couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all'`

So to avoid such errors I prefer to use the tilde sign for version number in gemfile
 Example:

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 4.2.1'
```

`~>` makes the bundler to update the gem until version reaches to `4.2.9` and wont update if version reaches to `4.3.0`

- You know that if drastic changes occur in the gem then version number must reach `4.3.0`
- Update the gem if you know what changes have been made exactly and you are ready to upgrade.

Comment: https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/03/18/ruby-on-rails-gemfile-bundler-couldnt-find-file-jquery-ui-all/

Answer (score 2):

Restart the server to fix this issue.

Worked for me.