# Sprockets::FileNotFound in Preorder#index

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When i run the app i get this error

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Preorder#index
couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all'
```

Showing /selfstarter/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all'
  (in /selfstarter/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:14)
Extracted source (around line #6):

```
3:   <head>
4:     <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
5:     <title><%= Settings.product_name %></title>
6:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
7:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
8:   </head>
9:   <!--[if lt IE 9 ]><body class="lt-ie9"><![endif]-->
```

Rails.root: /selfstarter

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___3248970066533973388_70154235929540'

Someone has asked this questions here [ruby on rails ails with couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374842/ruby-on-rails-ails-with-couldnt-find-file-jquery-ui-all) .I have tried all the responses in this question but none of them worked

Comment: that's because you are requiring that file in your application.css but it isn't present. Also isn't jquery.ui is a js file so what is it doing in your stylesheets ?

Comment: Thanks.I have cloned a repo and it was working previously but when i integrated some other functionalities in it ,this error about missing jquery file came up